# java generics with wildcards

Tags: java, generics, effective-java

Can someone please explain to me difference between extends and super in java generics with wildcards?

I have read related posts and didn't get complete understanding. If you could explain me with real time example that would be great help for me.

what does PECS(producer you extend, consumes you use super) mean?

Comment: maybe you want to read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/wildcardGuidelines.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type parameter <? extends T> means T or any subclass of T.

The type parameter <? super T> means T or any superclass of T.

For example:

- Iterable<? extends T> supports any iterator whose next() method returns a T. This includes iterators that return a subclass of T.
- Collection<? super T> supports any collection into which T's can be placed. This includes collections that can hold objects of any superclass of T.

In *Effective Java*, Joshua Bloch recommends the mnemonic **PECS** -- for "Producer-Extends, Consumer-Super".

> "If a parameterized type represents a T producer, use `<? extends T>`;
>   if it represents a T consumer, use `<? super T>`."

This is also known as the *Get and Put Principle,* from *Java Generics* by Maurice Naftalin and Philip Wadler.

> "Use an `extends` wildcard when you only *get* values out of a structure, use a `super` wildcard when you only *put* values into a structure, and don't use a wildcard when you *both* get and put."

Answer (score 3):

If you have classes A, B and C where

A extends B

and

B extends C

Then

A and B match:

? extends B

and

B and C match:

? super B